# What is the difference between "Filing Date" and "Accepted" date in EDGAR?

Tags: united-states, sec, annual-report, electronic-filing, edgar

In [Apple's 2019 Form 10-K filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/0000320193-19-000119-index.html) on EDGAR, I see this:

[image: AAPL 2019 Form 10-K filing information on EDGAR]

What is the difference between "Filing Date" and "Accepted" date?

In some filings, the "Filing Date" and "Accepted" date are the same, while in others, the dates are different.

Comment: For the examples where the dates are the same, what are the times? Are they during "working hours"? My first thought is that if the (presumably electronic) document arrives late in the day (6:12pm in your example) it is "Filed" on the next (working?) day. But that's just a guess.

Comment: 1) Your image doesn't match your link as I reach Coca-cola as the SEC Accession No doesn't match. 2) See:`How can I understand EDGAR Timestamps?` from https://www.sec.gov/os/webmaster-faq and possibly https://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/pdsdissemspec051310.pdf

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have fixed the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filing date is when the information was uploaded onto the EDGAR system.

After that, per this document:

`https://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/pdsdissemspec051310.pdf`

there is a "rigorous series of syntactic and semantic validation rules" that the submission is run through. If it passes, then the submission is reassembled with header tags, and disseminated throughout the system.

That acceptance and dissemination process usually takes less than two minutes.

Another aspect of your question - the filing date field doesn't include time information, only the date itself.